# Can't find gnutls ibrary when executing rpmbuild under non-root

Tags: rpm, gnutls

I am trying to build ntgs from the latest source, using the .spec from rpmforge - as non-root via rpmbuild. During the compile, it fails at this step:

```
checking for GNUTLS... no
configure: error: ntfsprogs crypto code requires the gnutls library.
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.78913 (%build)
```

However, I can compile it successfully outside of rpmbuild. So it sounds like it just the matter of library being seen during the build. However, I can confirm that rpmbuild can see the library that gnutls resides:

```
[foo@bar ~]$ rpmbuild -E '%{_libdir}' rpmbuild/SPECS/ntfsprogs.spec 
/usr/lib
```

Library location:

```
[foo@bar ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2012.1.15]$ /sbin/ldconfig -p | grep -i gnutls
        libgnutls.so.13 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libgnutls.so.13
        libgnutls.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/libgnutls.so
        libgnutls-openssl.so.13 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libgnutls-openssl.so.13
        libgnutls-openssl.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/libgnutls-openssl.so
        libgnutls-extra.so.13 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libgnutls-extra.so.13
        libgnutls-extra.so (libc6) => /usr/lib/libgnutls-extra.so
```

What would cause the problem of the library not being seen when you build a RPM?

EDIT: Oh yeah, I am running Centos 5.5.

Comment: Run this as your rpmbuild user to see where your library is installed: `/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep -i gnutls`

Comment: Updated with output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 2012.1.15 of ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs requires gnutls >= 1.4.4 but RHEL5 only provides 1.4.1. You were able to compile it outside of rpmbuild because you didn't specify `--enable-crypto` in your `configure` which the spec file does. These problems can be identified by examining `config.log`.

In general, handling a version bump of this magnitude--in this case from 1.13.1 (Feb 22 2007) to 2012.1.15--will be more involved that simply editing the "Version:" line in the spec file.

Also note that the EPEL repo has version 2011.4.12 ( http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/repoview/ntfsprogs.html ) which may be new enough for you. If you have already installed rpmforge packages on your system I urge caution as rpmforge and EPEL do not work well together.

Comment: Ah, okay. Looks like it is going to be a lot more work for me. :| Thanks!